# Read data from a text file and create and object but text have different object information

Tags: java

I need some help: I'm making a Internship Management Program  on Java, but I've got one problem, I have a text file (input.txt) where I have all the student and instructors information  on it for example:

Department,CME,Computer Engineering,Assoc.Prof.Dr.,Mehmet Hilal OZCANHAN,Res.Asst.,Elife KIYAK,Res.Asst.,Goksu  TUYSUZOGLU,Hardware Training,2,Software Training,4,Free,6
Department,CEV,Environmental Engineering,Prof.Dr.,Ayse GUR,Res.Asst.,Sibel TOSUN,Res.Asst.,Ahmet TARAK,Practical  Training,3,Theoretical Training,2,Free,5

I have categorize them using the Student class and after that  I have to list all classes.

```
public class Date {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
}
```

```
public class Phone {
    private int phone_country_code;
    private int phone_area_code;
    private int phone_number;

    public Phone(int phone_country_code, int phone_area_code, int phone_number) {
        super();
        this.phone_country_code = phone_country_code;
        this.phone_area_code = phone_area_code;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }
}
```

```
public class Student {
    private int student_number;
    private String student_name;
    private String gender;
    private Phone student_phone;
    private Date student_birthdate;
    public Student(int student_number, String student_name, String gender, Phone student_phone,
            Date student_birthdate) {
        super();
        this.student_number = student_number;
        this.student_name = student_name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.student_phone = student_phone;
        this.student_birthdate = student_birthdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Also show your existing code.

Comment: Thx for help, i have edited my post i have classes like Phone ,Adress,Student,Date etc. I need to read a txt file for inputs and i need to fill students informations .After that the information have to be shown . Like press 1

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Why don't to read the file line by line and create objects? Show you code.